# NullPointerException for Query

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I got `NullPointerException` error after using `toString().substring()` . I need to use this method. Help me please. I am not very sure i can use that method inside the query.

Orginal

```
String selectItemMasDetl="select MMITNO,MMITDS,MMALUN,MMSPUN from"+DBConnect.SCHEMA+".mitmas where MMCONO=888 and MMITNO="+ItemNo+"'";
```

Use `ToString().substring()`

```
 String selectItemMasDetl="select MMITNO,MMITDS,MMALUN,MMSPUN from"+DBConnect.SCHEMA+".mitmas where MMCONO=888 and MMITNO="+ItemNo.toString().substring(0,4)+"'";
```

error log

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
[12/13/11 16:24:28:594 SGT]  a6cc007 SystemErr     R    at com.------erp.report.stocklotsalesreport.StockLotSalesReportGet.getItemMasDetl
```

ANS:

```
selectItmMas="select MMITNO,MMITDS,MMALUN,MMSPUN from "+DBConnect.SCHEMA+".mitmas where MMCONO=888 and MMITNO like '"+ salesRecordListTO.getItemNo().trim() +"%'";
```

I use like operator and pass parameter instead of using trim. Now i get the result i want.
Thank you so much guys.

Comment: What is `ItemNo`? The syntax highlighting suggests it's a type.  If it's a variable, its first letter should be lowercase to avoid confusion.  If it's a type, you should not be defining a static `toString()` method on it, since `toString()` is one of the standard methods on Object and defining it as a static method will lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It means that at least in some cases either `ItemNo` or, `DBConnect` or the returned value of the `toString()` (as suggested) is `null`. The problem is that you don't have a stack trace, and so you can't be sure where the error is thrown. It could be even on another line, for what we (don't) know now.

Try to wrap with a `try` `catch` the relevant lines and print a stack trace, check the line of code where is happening, and post here again. Here is how:

```
try {
    //code throwing exception
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Side note: seems that you need a space after the from, also you're closing a single quote, but I don't see the opening. Below, for reference, your code, only reformatted, not fixed:

```
String selectItemMasDetl = "select MMITNO,MMITDS,MMALUN,MMSPUN from"
    + DBConnect.SCHEMA + ".mitmas where MMCONO=888 and MMITNO="
    + ItemNo.toString().substring(0,4) + "'";
```

Comment: It's also possible (though unlikely) that `ItemNo.toString()` is returning null.

Comment: Right, or the error could be in another line entirely, I don't see a stack trace.

Comment: That is true.  I think though, that DBConnect is not null, because the OP implied that the first code snippet worked.

Comment: i left single quote and fixed it now. but still got error. the item no: is not null.

Comment: Yes, that was the side note, also add the missing space after from, wrap the code in the try catch, look at the class name and line number at the top of the stack trace, find it in your code and update us. You'll still have the error, but at least you will know where!

Comment: Hi all, i add my way of solving in the question. thanks for your helps and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerExeption` means that ItemNo is null, so when trying to use `ItemNo.toString()`, it will be interpreted as `null.toString()` which will throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

A check on null is one possibility (the easiest), see answer of Stivlo.

Depending on how quick the query is a count query can be done also, if count ==0 don't bother to do the real query.

Oops, sorry, not reading good: the null exception is already in building the query string. Well maybe this is of use in your next nullpointer exception :)

StringBuilder might be a solution, but than I think you'll get an invalid querystring, just use Stivlo's answer.